# What is the greatest power of 2 that is a factor of $10^{1002}-4^{501}$? (2014 AMC10B #17)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I've been stuck on a problem for the whole day:

**What is the greatest power of 2 that is a factor of $10^{1002}-4^{501}$?**

Immediately, I set out to attempt it via some tried & tested methods:

- *Difference of Squares*:

  $({ 10 }^{ 501 }-{ 4 }^{ \frac { 501 }{ 2 }  })({ 10 }^{ 501 }+{ 4 }^{ \frac { 501 }{ 2 }  })$ got me nowhere.
- *Factoring*

  Neither does ${ (2*5) }^{ 1002 }-{ ({ 2 }^{ 2 }) }^{ 501 }\\ { 2 }^{ 1002 }({ 5 }^{ 1002 }-1)$ apparently
- *Smaller Numbers*

  I tried think of smaller cases, such as ${ 2 }^{ 13 }|{ 10 }^{ 10 }-{ 4 }^{ 5 }\\ $ or ${ 2 }^{ 17 }|{ 10 }^{ 14 }-{ 4 }^{ 7 }\\ $, but I could not sense any pattern. Perhaps Euclid's Extended Algorithm could be used via some method. Any **hints** on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed it suffices to find $\nu_2(5^{1002} -1)$.

We will use a very useful lemma, namely [lifting the exponent](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/).

Which says for $p=2$, when $p\nmid x,p\nmid y $ then the following identity holds:
$$\nu_2(x^n-y^n) =\nu_2(x-y)+\nu_2(x+y)+\nu_2(n)-1 $$
Applying this we obtain

$$ \nu_2(5^{1002} -1)=2+1+1-1=3  $$

Comment: I've never seen the LTE lemma, and I'm wondering, why exactly must the conditions $p\nmid x,p\nmid y$ exist for us to conclude that ${ v }_{ p }({ x }^{ n }-{ y }^{ n })={ v }_{ p }(x-y)+{ v }_{ p }(x+y)+{ v }_{ p }(n)-1$?

Comment: And, to be honest, this relationship seems very "out of the blue", and not intuitive, for me.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- $\;10^{1002}=(2 \cdot 5)^{1002}= 2^{2 \cdot 501} \cdot 5^{1002}=\cdots$
- $5^{1002}-1=(4+1)^{1002}-1 = 4 \cdot\left(4^{1001}+ \cdots + \binom{1002}{2} \cdot 4 + 1002\right)$

Answer (score 3):

$$10^{1002}-4^{501} = 5^{1002}\cdot 2^{1002}-2^{1002} = 2^{1002}\cdot\left(5^{1002}-1\right)$$
so $\nu_2(\text{LHS})=1002+\nu_2\left(5^{1002}-1\right)$. Of course $5^{1002}-1$ is a multiple of $4$, since $5\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and it is enough to consider the remainders of $5^{1002}-1$ $\pmod{8}$ and $\pmod{16}$.

Spoiler alert:

> By Euler's theorem
>  $$ 5^{1002}-1 \equiv 5^{2}-1 \equiv 0\pmod{8}, $$
>  but
>  $$ 5^{1002}-1 \equiv 5^{2}-1 \not\equiv 0\pmod{16}, $$
>  so $\nu_2\left(5^{1002}-1\right)=3$ and the answer to the given question is  $1002+3=\color{red}{1005}$.

Comment: Didn't OP ask for hints?

Comment: @AaronQuitta: all right, answer re-designed.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track when you considered some smaller cases. But even the simplest pattern might not become apparent after you look at just two cases. If you'd looked at a few more, then perhaps you'd have seen a pattern which would suggest the answer which others have already provided.